# Converting java object into XML?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Java object and trying to achieve XML generation in the cleanest way possible.

## Desired XML

```
<fes:PropertyIsLessThan matchAction="ANY" matchCase="false">

  <fes:ValueReference>name</fes:ValueReference>

  <fes:Function name="sub">

    <fes:Literal>my-id</fes:Literal>

  </fes:Function>

</fes:PropertyIsLessThan>

<fes:And>

  <fes:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo matchAction="ANY" matchCase="false">

    <fes:ValueReference>attName</fes:ValueReference>

    <fes:Literal>5</fes:Literal>

  </fes:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>

  <fes:PropertyIsLike escapeChar="\" matchCase="false" singleChar="?" wildCard="*">

    <fes:ValueReference>title</fes:ValueReference>

    <fes:Literal>greetings</fes:Literal>

  </fes:PropertyIsLike>

</fes:And>
```

I'm using filter functions as found here: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function.html

I see there is JaxB out there that may help with conversion of a POJO to XML. But what is out there to make this task fairly straight forward? I'm trying to understand the process of how a class can get converted to a valid XML like the following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [OGC Schemas Project](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) which compiles OGC Schemas for JAXB.

I guess you're using OGC Filter schema in one of the versions (probably 2.0). The [OGC Schemas Project](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) provides pre-compiled OGC Schemas, including Filter schemas.

In order to use it, import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.ogc</groupId>
    <artifactId>filter-v_2_0</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

into your project. Then you could create a `JAXBContext` with the context path `"net.opengis.filter.v_2_0:net.opengis.ows.v_1_1_0:org.hisrc.w3c.xlink.v_1_0"`. You could use this `JAXBContext` to unmarshal XML and marshal object structures.

Comment: This looks promising. Are there any examples anywhere using this to help point me to the right direction? Haven't used any of this before.

Comment: @RyanHack Here's a [test case](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas/blob/master/filter/1.1.0/src/test/java/net/opengis/filter/v_1_1_0/tests/Filter_Test.java) from `Filter 1.1.0`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I seem to be getting some crazy errors right off the bat trying to do this. Any chance we could jump into chat?

Comment: @RyanHack A chat probably not but might help with a sample project on GitHub.

Comment: The xml to pojo is super super cool. I'm just looking for direction into how I can take a standard pojo that has some information and help map it into this filter 2.0 xml using jaxb with your library

Comment: @RyanHack You have to build this object structure together. Create objects, assign properties etc. This is how it works with JAXB.

Comment: ok, cool. Are there any examples demonstrating this direction from pojo to xml with filter 2.0?

Comment: It's from my understanding the classes can be auto generated from the xsd?

Comment: @RyanHack They already are in the mentioned project. That's the point, you don't need to generate anything, just use the provided JARs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165508/discussion-between-ryan-hack-and-lexicore).